# How to build a flowcover in gwt?

Tags: gwt, user-interface, user-controls

I want to build a `flowCover` in GWT. But I don't know how to do it. 
Have anyone an idea? Or a sample?

Greetz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with examples implementing it using CSS and see how you can copy their Javascript logic and make a similar widget: http://paulbakaus.com/2008/05/31/coverflow-anyone/ and http://scottgale.com/blog/coverflow-css-3d-transforms/2011/05/24/